# How to use wavesurfer.js in xamarin forms android?Can anybody have idea?

Tags: javascript, xamarin, wavesurfer.js

Right now im trying to load file from internal device,

```
Working code:
enter code here
    wavesurfer.load('file:///assests_content/rooster.wav');
        alert('hi2');
```

Not working code:

```
    wavesurfer.load('file:///storage/emulated/0/new/rooster.wav');
        alert('hi2');
```

Comment: This might be a permissions issue. Is there any error message you can share?

Comment: How to get error message in xamarin for js?

Comment: If the file(s) are not within your app's sandbox, your would need to implement a content provider to retrieve the content-based uri. You can do this via a dependency service.

Comment: Try to load that file as a binary using the file system commands. You can either use the platform specific file system commands or you can use a library like PCLStorage. In either case, if the access to that file is getting denied you will get an error message.

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfect, I fixed it using loading the file as the blob.

```js
"<html>
            <head>
                <script src=""https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js""></script>
                <script src=""wavesurfer.spectrogram.js""></script>
            </head>
            <body>
<h1>Xamarin.Forms</h1>
<p>Welcome to WebView.</p>
    <div id=""waveform""></div>
<div id=""spectrogm""></div>
    <div id=""MyTest"">my divs</div>
    <script>
try{
        alert('hi');
        var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
            container: '#waveform',
            waveColor: 'violet',
            progressColor: 'purple',
            plugins: [
                    WaveSurfer.spectrogram.create({
                        wavesurfer: wavesurfer,
                        container: ""#spectrogm""
                    })
                ]
        });
            alert('hi2');
}
catch(err)
{
    alert(err.message);
}

function readTextFile(file)
{
try
{
    var blob = null;
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open(""GET"", file);
    rawFile.responseType = ""blob"";//force the HTTP response, response-type header to be blob
    rawFile.onload = function()
        {
            blob = rawFile.response;//xhr.response is now a blob object
            alert('blob');
            wavesurfer.loadBlob(blob);
        }
    rawFile.send();
    alert('completed');
}
catch(err)
{
    alert('error');
    alert(err);
}
}
readTextFile('file:///storage/emulated/0/new/rooster.wav');
```